# Why doesn't python logging.exception method log traceback by default?

Tags: python, exception, python-logging

When writing defensive code in python (e.g. you're handling some user input or whatever), I find it useful to return `Exception` objects alongside regular computation results, so they can be discarded/logged or processed in some other way. Consider the following snippet:

```py
import logging
from traceback import TracebackException
from typing import Union

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)


def _compute(x) -> int:
    return len(x)


def compute(x) -> Union[int, Exception]:
    try:
        return _compute(x)
    except Exception as e:
        return e


inputs = [
    'whatever',
    1,
    'ooo',
    None,
]


outputs = []
for i in inputs:
    r = compute(i)
    outputs.append(r)


for i, r in zip(inputs, outputs):
    logging.info('compute(%s)', i)
    if isinstance(r, Exception):
        logging.exception(r)
    else:
        logging.info(r)
```

This results in the following output

```
INFO:root:compute(whatever)
INFO:root:8
INFO:root:compute(1)
ERROR:root:object of type 'int' has no len()
NoneType: None
INFO:root:compute(ooo)
INFO:root:3
INFO:root:compute(None)
ERROR:root:object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
NoneType: None
```

So you can see that useful exception information like stacktrace is lost, which makes it a bit hard to debug the cause of exception.

This can be fixed by logging exception as `logging.exception(r, exc_info=r)`:

```
INFO:root:compute(whatever)
INFO:root:8
INFO:root:compute(1)
ERROR:root:object of type 'int' has no len()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 15, in compute
    return _compute(x)
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 10, in _compute
    return len(x)
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
INFO:root:compute(ooo)
INFO:root:3
INFO:root:compute(None)
ERROR:root:object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 15, in compute
    return _compute(x)
  File "/tmp/test.py", line 10, in _compute
    return len(x)
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

My question is -- why doesn't `logging.exception` method do this by default, if the argument passed to it happens to be an `Exception`? I tried searching in PEPs/etc but wasn't really fruitful.

My only guess is that `logging.exception` is essentially [just a special case of `logging.error`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1868-L1872), so in principle `logging.exception` method doesn't know whether is' passed an `Exception` object or something else. So supporting this would require some code, e.g. checking whether `isinstance(msg, Exception)`, and perhaps the authors of logging library decided it's a bit too specific. But IMO it makes sense considering in practice in most cases `logging.exception` is passed an `Exception` object.

Comment: @brian Bizarre or not, I find returning/yielding `Exception` objects quite useful for flexible and quck error handling. I described my approach [here](https://beepb00p.xyz/mypy-error-handling.html#kiss, maybe it will convince you it's a reasonable thing to do :)

Comment: It seems that there is a method to your madness :). That does seem more sensible now. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2):

`logging.exception` *does* log the traceback by default. However, you're using it wrong. As the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.exception) say,

> This function should only be called from an exception handler.

`logging.exception` does not expect to be passed an exception instance, or any sort of exception information whatsoever. It uses [`sys.exc_info`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.exc_info) to gather info about the exception currently being handled, which only works if an exception *is* currently being handled. If you call it outside of an exception handler, it breaks.

Comment: Thanks, I guess that bit of documentation is a fair answer. 
Before posting a question I also read the [bit of code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1610-L1634) resposnible for logging, and if `exc_info` is passed explicitly, it does extract the traceback from the exception object.

Comment: Also `exc_info` is [exposed](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/logging/__init__.py#L1520-L1524) in `logging.exception` method, so seems that it is supposed to be used outside of exception handler? Otherwise not sure what's the point of exposing it. Not sure why it's not in the documentation though.

Answer (score 0):

While it still doesn't answer the question why, I came up with a workaround:

You can define a `Filter` object that automatically adds `exc_info` to any exceptions, regardless whether they are called from the exception handler or not.

```py
class AddExceptionTraceback(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        s = super().filter(record)
        if s is False:
            return False
        if record.levelname == 'ERROR':
            exc = record.msg
            if isinstance(exc, BaseException):
                if record.exc_info is None or record.exc_info == (None, None, None):
                    exc_info = (type(exc), exc, exc.__traceback__)
                    record.exc_info = exc_info
        return s

logger.addFilter(AddExceptionTraceback())
```

I used it for a while now without any issues whatsoever, so maybe it'd help someone else.